# Java get path of class

Tags: java, class, path

How can I retrieve the path to a class in the following format:

```
package.package.class
```

I tried the following but it gives me the path with slashes instead of the format above:

```
System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Instead I want to get java.io.File for the code above. How is this possible?

Comment: `File.class.getCanonicalName()`?

Comment: May I ask why you wanna do that? Maybe there is a better way if we know what are you trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you just want to get the full path of the 'File' class.

Try:

```
System.out.println(File.class.getName());
```